# Match of rows between two files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

masterdf:

[image: masterdf]

```
code    name
K   Transcription
L   Replication, recombination and repair
M   Cell wall/membrane/envelope biosynthesis
S   Function unknown
```

mydf:

[image: mydf]

```
query   code
1   S
2   K
3   MK
4   LS
5   -
```

My `masterdf` is so-to-say a database that has the two important columns code and name. My `mydf` has the important column code.

Now, I would like to match the two tables based on the two code columns. `S` therefore stands for "Function unknown", and `MK` stands for both "Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis" & "Transcription"

Of note, the `masterdf` has a record for every single letter, but the letter in `mydf` can be composed of 2+ letters.

I can do it if I just have a one-letter code:

```
mydf.merge(masterdf,on='code').sort_values("query")
```

How can I get the text when there's a combination of letters?

My expected output (the `name` is here combined by `&`):

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to getting this to work is to expand the `code` column in `mydf` into a list, then `explode` the dataframe into more rows based on that list. Once you do that, you can merge the two dataframes, then aggregate the results.

```
import pandas as pd

masterdf = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'S', '-'],
                         'name': ['Transcription', 'Replication, recombination and repair',
                                  'Cell wall/membrane/envelope biosynthesis',
                                  'Function unknown', '-']})
print(masterdf)

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'query': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'code': ['S', 'K', 'MK', 'LS', '-']})
print(mydf)
```

Note that I added a row for `-` to `masterdf`. You should be able to add this after you load the dataframe, if you're loading from a file.

The first step splits `'MK'` into `[M, K]` and `'LS'` into `[L, S]`. All other codes will be a list of one element.

```
# Expand the code column into a list of characters
mydf['code'] = mydf.apply(lambda row: list(row['code']), axis=1)
print(mydf)
```

Output:

```
   query    code
0      1     [S]
1      2     [K]
2      3  [M, K]
3      4  [L, S]
4      5     [-]
```

The next step makes rows with multiple codes into multiple rows instead, allowing you to merge in the next step.

```
# Explode the code list into multiple rows
mydf = mydf.explode('code')
print(mydf)
```

Output:

```
   query code
0      1    S
1      2    K
2      3    M
2      3    K
3      4    L
3      4    S
4      5    -
```

Merging brings in the `name` column from `masterdf`.

```
# Merge the two dataframes (how='left' preserves the order in the code column)
merged_df = mydf.merge(masterdf, on='code', how='left').sort_values(['query'])
print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
   query code                                      name
0      1    S                          Function unknown
1      2    K                             Transcription
2      3    M  Cell wall/membrane/envelope biosynthesis
3      3    K                             Transcription
4      4    L     Replication, recombination and repair
5      4    S                          Function unknown
6      5    -                                         -
```

The last step aggregates the expanded rows back together into the desired result.

```
# Aggregate the rows back together, grouped by query.
# Join individual codes back to their original values.
# Join corresponding names with &.
df = merged_df.groupby('query').agg({'code': lambda x: ''.join(x.tolist()),
                                     'name': lambda x: ' & '.join(x.tolist())})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      code                                               name
query                                                        
1        S                                   Function unknown
2        K                                      Transcription
3       MK  Cell wall/membrane/envelope biosynthesis & Tra...
4       LS  Replication, recombination and repair & Functi...
5        -                                                  -
```

Comment: thank you! As in my real example I have more fields with a dash, I ran `df.replace(r'(-)\1{1,}', r'\1', regex=True)` to get rid of aggregated dashes.